# How do you deploy a .NET application to cPanel?

Tags: .net, .net-core, cpanel

I need to deploy a .NET Core application to GoDaddy (using cPanel).

Hopefully there is someone out there that has deployed a .NET Core application to cPanel before and could offer me some guidance?

(It looks like I could use a plugin called NexusCore?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a question for cPanel support. I suggest you email their sales team

Comment: Hi JBoothUA,

It seems they don't support .net core on their Cpanel. But, to make sure, you can contact their support team. If you want to use .net core on Linux, try DigitalOcean. For Windows, I would recommend Asphostportal.